# EdgesHelper does not work

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to draw the edges of a bunch of cubes using the `EdgesHelper` class. I'm following [this example](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/63997063/Three.JS.EdgesHelper.html) but i'm unable to reproduce the effect in my demo:

```
Demo = function(dom, width, height, n){
  this.dom = dom;

  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;

  this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, alpha: false});
  this.renderer.setSize(width, height );
  this.renderer.autoClear = false;

  this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, width/height, 1, 1000);

  this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
  this.light = new THREE.PointLight(0x8844ff, 5, 100);
  this.scene.add(this.light);

  var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(5, 5, 5);
  var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial();

  for (var i = 0; i < n; i ++) {
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

    mesh.position.x = Math.random()*200 - 100;
    mesh.position.y = Math.random()*200 - 100;
    mesh.position.z = Math.random()*200 - 100;
    mesh.rotation.x = Math.random();
    mesh.rotation.y = Math.random();

    this.scene.add(mesh);

    var edges = new THREE.EdgesHelper(mesh, 0xffffff);
    edges.material.linewidth = 2;

    this.scene.add(edges);
  }

  this.dom.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);
};

Demo.prototype = {

  dom: null,

  width: 0,
  height: 0,

  renderer: null,

  scene: null,
  camera: null,
  light: null,
  objects: null,

  update: function(t) {
    this.camera.lookAt(this.scene.position);

    this.light.position.x = Math.sin( t * 5 ) * 100;
    this.light.position.z = Math.cos( t * 5 ) * 100;

    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);      
  }

}
```

This code only outputs two vertical lines. When i remove the line `this.scene.add(edges);` the cubes are displayed correctly. What is wrong with it?

Comment: Your material color defaults to white and your edges are set to white.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this working fiddle link... make changes in your code....three.jsr69  http://jsfiddle.net/ebeit303/grr308Lx/116/

```js
var width = window.innerWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight;
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true,
  alpha: false
});
renderer.setSize(width, height);
renderer.autoClear = true;
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, width / height, 1, 1000);

var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 5, 100);
scene.add(light);

var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(5, 5, 5);
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
  color: 0xff0000
});

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

  mesh.position.x = 28 - (7 * i);
  mesh.position.y = Math.random() * 20 - (1 * i);
  mesh.position.z = -59; //Math.random()*20 - 100;
  mesh.rotation.x = Math.random();
  mesh.rotation.y = Math.random();
  scene.add(mesh);
  var edges = new THREE.EdgesGeometry(geometry);
  var line = new THREE.LineSegments(edges, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
    color: 0x0000ff
  }));
  mesh.add(line);
  /*var edges = new THREE.EdgesHelper( mesh, 0x0000ff);
  edges.material.linewidth = 2;

  scene.add(edges);*/
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  renderer.render(scene, camera);

}
animate();
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/three@0.121.1/build/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: for three.jsr68 working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ebeit303/Hxkw2/, use THREE.WireframeHelper instead of THREE.Edgeshelper

Comment: WireframeHelper will, unfortunately, render diagonals.

Comment: @Ferdi265 In three.js Face4 has been removed and face3 only using to construct mesh.

Comment: I know. to fix that, I used a self-made function that does what EdgesHelper does, but returns the geometry for the Line constructor

Comment: here is a fix, its a partial edgehelper by my own.. http://jsfiddle.net/ebeit303/2nj0vnuc/

Comment: @ferdi265 Three.js r69 support edgeshelper.. check the link.. http://jsfiddle.net/ebeit303/grr308Lx/

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a problem with your ligth, you add 2 not initialized ligths:

```
this.light = new THREE.PointLight(0x8844ff, 5, 100);
this.scene.add(this.light1);
this.scene.add(this.light2);
```

Comment: Oops, copy and paste fail. The code should be correct now. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this- It's working fine at my side.

```
//this.scene.add(mesh);//Comment here.
var body = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
var edges = new THREE.EdgesHelper(body , '#C0C0C0');
this.scene.add(edges);
```